# How to display an image in a Jupyter Notebook with Julia?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I have some image data like the following:

```
224×224×3×2 Array{Float32, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   …  0.384314  0.396078  0.403922
 0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   0.117647      0.384314  0.392157  0.4
 0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   0.117647      0.384314  0.388235  0.392157
 0.121569   0.117647   0.121569   0.121569      0.388235  0.388235  0.388235
 0.12549    0.117647   0.12549    0.129412      0.396078  0.396078  0.396078
```

which I was using for some ML models. I want to be able to visualize the images in a notebook.

Right now I can do `ImageView.imshow` but that opens the image outside of the notebook. How can I display the image inside of the notebook?

Comment: Maybe `Makie.image` could help: https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/examples/plotting_functions/image/#example_3614004436634172483. However, I can't tell what kind of data structure this function expects based on the signature (`image(image)`, really?), so that may not work for this 4D array

Comment: What is the 2 in the last dimension? Is this the data for 2 images?

Comment: Yes, two images in one array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
IJulia.display(image)
```

For an example:

```
using Images
image = [RGB(rand(N0f8,3)...) for x in 1:200, y in 1:150]
using IJulia
IJulia.display(image)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer the question as asked? This describes how to create an RGB image array, but the question is about an already existing array that contains `Float32`s. Doing an `IJulia.display` on that array only prints the array numerically as in the question. Could you perhaps add a section how to convert that given array into a format suitable for this kind of `display`?

Comment: If you tell me how to convert `3×2 Array` to `RGB` - sure. The question has no information how colors are encoded. The standard way to represent colors in computing is RGB or RGB+alpha and the way to process that in Julia is `Images.RGB`. Since we have no information on the last dimension than nothing more can be said. On the other hand if you know how color is encoded  then the conversion to `RGB` is trivia (perhpas using `reinterpret` or similar)

Comment: If I just have `224×224×3 Array{Float32, 3}`, when I do display, I just get the number, not an image. How would I resolve this?

Comment: I posted an updated more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069169/how-to-display-a-224-224-3-image-in-a-jupyter-notebook-with-julia since your answer is technically correct given the question title but I still need some clarity